# Rails 6 with webpack: ReferenceError: <js_function> is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, turbolinks

`getPopover()` is a jquery function from `settings.js` and the file is imported in `application.js`

```
...
// Initialize custom javascript
import('../javascripts/settings.js');

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    getPopover();
  }
);
```

During initial page load the errors occurs:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getPopover is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (application.js:38)
at Object.o.dispatch (turbolinks.js:75)
at e.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.js:994)
at e.pageLoaded (turbolinks.js:948)
at turbolinks.js:872

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getPopover is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (settings.js:18)
at l (jquery.js:2838)
at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:2887)
at _.fn.init._.fn.ready (jquery.js:3108)
at new _.fn.init (jquery.js:2618)
at t (jquery.js:58)
at Module.<anonymous> (settings.js:4)
at Module.659 (1-a0dc9e1b601c4940d32b.chunk.js:1)
at r (bootstrap:63)
```

The **settings.js** starts with:

```
$(function() {
...
  $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '.tooltip-button, [data-toggle="tooltip"]'
  });

  getPopover();
  ...

  window.getPopover = function() {
    $('body').popover({
      container: 'body',
      ...
```

It seems the function is not loaded yet when `turbolinks:load` call comes in.
Could anyone advice how to solve it, please?

Comment: Can you please show **settings.js** file and also settings.js full path.

Comment: @code_aks the **settings.js** file is huge and I cannot show it, but I edited the question above to show how is called... to be clear, all other functions are loaded, the only problem is with **turbolinks**. The full path is _app/javascript/javascripts/settings.js_

Comment: @sOrin, you called getPopover() function before definition?

Comment: @NeK i am afraid this is the case and i don't know how to avoid it

Comment: Please don't call function before it's definition.

Comment: @NeK How can I do it in my case?

Comment: You're calling getPopover(); and then later on in the flow you're defining it...change that.